# Order of precedence of CSS rules

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

If more than one CSS rule applies to an *element* and specifies the same property, 
then CSS gives priority to the rule that has the more specific selector.

That means,
An ID selector is more specific than a class selector, which in turn is more 
specific than a tag selector, as shown below,

```css
#id1 {
  color: blue;
}
.class1 {
  color: red;
}
p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p class="class1" id="id1">Sham</p>
```

the output is a paragraph text in `blue` color.

For the below code,

```css
p[data-colour] {
  color: yellow;
}
#id1 {
  color: blue;
}
.class1 {
  color: red;
}
p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p class="class1" id="id1" data-colour>Sham</p>
```

With respect to *attribute selectors*, What does CSS rule specificity say?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info at css specifity selector :)

Comment: Here is a specificity calculator that never fails to come in useful: https://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-specificity/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still `blue`. Attribute selectors are on the same level as classes. For more information see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: `.class1` is a synonym of `[class~=class1]`, so they have same specificity.